# Can I skip the "try different control options" screen?

Tags: super-mario-odyssey

Every time I start up Super Mario Odyssey, it reminds me I can play with detached Joycons and that there are other control styles.

I don't want to change styles, and this screen seems to take forever. Is there any way to skip it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This screen cannot be skipped. It is actually a loading screen, and will not stay in place any longer than it should take to load. Essentially, if you were able to hide or skip it, you would instead be watching a black screen or a different screen for the remaining duration.

While I could not find "official" statements on this fact, there's anecdotal evidence that supports it. For example, on [this messageboard](http://www.nintendolife.com/forums/nintendo-switch/try_playing_with_detached_joy-con_controllers), or [on reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/NintendoSwitch/comments/79btoa/for_the_love_of_all_that_is_holy_let_me_skip_this/).